# Hosting Multiple .NET Core Web Apps on Linux Nginx in Subdirectories Static Files Not Loading (CSS, JS, etc)

Tags: nginx, .net-core

I have a few .net core apps (.NET Core 7) which I would like to host in their own subdirectories (subdomain.domain.co.za/api, subdomain.domain.co.za/auth and subdomain.domain.co.za/proxy). I have been trying to figure out why static files (css, js files hosted in the wwwroot folder) are returning HTTP 404. From the console, I see the web app is trying to load the resources from the root directory which I dont understand because the files are all within each subdirectory. I am hosting everything on a Linux Ubuntu 22.04 VPS.

Here is the nginx server block file for my 3 apps:

```
    server {
        server_name subdomain.domain.co.za www.subdomain.domain.co.za;
        error_log /var/apps/domain.co.za/logs/domain.log;
        
        root /var/www/subdomain.domain.co.za;

        location /proxy/ {
         root /var/www/subdomain.domain.co.za/proxy;
         proxy_pass         http://localhost:8886/;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
         proxy_set_header   Host $host;
         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        location /auth/ {
         root /var/www/subdomain.domain.co.za/auth;
         proxy_pass         http://localhost:8888/;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
         proxy_set_header   Host $host;
         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;  
        }
    
        location /api/ {
         root /var/www/subdomain.domain.co.za/api;
         proxy_pass         http://localhost:8887/;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
         proxy_set_header   Host $host;
         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;  
        }
        
        location / {
         root /var/www/subdomain.domain.co.za;
         index index.html;
        }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.domain.co.za/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.domain.co.za/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}server {
    if ($host = www.subdomain.domain.co.za) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = subdomain.domain.co.za) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        
        server_name subdomain.domain.co.za www.subdomain.domain.co.za;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

In one of the apps (auth app), I had tried explicitly stating what the request path would be, and where to find the css, js related files:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("/var/www/subdomain.domain.co.za/auth/wwwroot"),
            RequestPath = "/auth"
        });
        app.UsePathBase("/auth");
```

This is what appears in dev tools console section:

[image]

I am not sure what else I could try, or what could be happening here.

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need to configure root path for your .net core apps. It might be even in your docker container. We are accessing the files over http. Not from static path in the nginx.

```
    location /auth/ {
     proxy_pass         http://localhost:8888/;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
     proxy_set_header   Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;  
    }
```

Second, you already setting your path prefix with UsePathBase method. There is no need to duplicate. I am assuming that your wwwroot already in your auth service. So you dont have to specify physcal path either.

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UsePathBase("/auth");
```

Let me know if it works or I am wrong with my assumption.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that the root path is not required. I removed root path from configuration and updated the app with those methods. The result is same. Only difference was when I removed the root config, nginx tries to get files from another location: 2023/06/17 09:18:34 [error] 799822#799822: *6 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: subdomain.domain.co.za, request: "GET /lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "subdomain.domain.co.za", referrer: "https://sudomain.domain.co.za/auth/"

Comment: GET /lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1 -> Your path does not start with auth ?